# cannot get app.local to a routing file

Tags: express

So, in my express.js 4.13.3. , in the `app.js` file I set an `app.local` var

`app.set('multimedia', __dirname + '/public/multimedia');`

then in the `routes/settings.js` I try to access that var like

```
var app = require('../app');
var dir = app.get('multimedia');
```

and I get `app.get is not a function`.

I also tried `var dir = app.get.multimedia;` and `var dir = app.locals('multimedia');` and `var dir = app.locals.multimedia;` and still nothing.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: See the similar question and solution in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301795/node-js-passing-object-from-server-js-to-external-modules/34301907#34301907

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have not defined what to do when `required('../app')` is called. You should do this using `module.exports` as shown below. Try one of these approaches to fix this problem.

**Approach 1:**

Add this line to the `app.js` file.

```
module.exports = app;
```

This simply says to export the `app` whenever `require('../app')` is called. If you use `require('routes/settings');` within the `app.js`, this line should be placed before the `require('routes/settings');` or it will not work.

**Approach 2:**

```
//change the `routes/settings.js` like this
module.exports = function (app) {//notice that you pass the app to this
    //............     
    var dir = app.get('multimedia');
    console.log(dir);
    //............
}
```

Add this line to `app.js`

```
require('routes/settings')(app);
```

Now you should be able to use the app.get() without any problem.

**Example:**

```
//app.js
var express=require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('multimedia', __dirname + '/public/multimedia');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

module.exports=app;

require('./settings');



//settings.js
var app= require('./app');

var dir = app.get('multimedia');

console.log(dir);
```

More details about module.exports can be found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Comment: The whole idea came to me since I saw that I can access a local var in the templating like so `<%= settings.nameOfTheVar %>`. So you are telling me that there is no easier way to get a local in the javascript code, like `app.set` and then , in another file, `app.get`? Anyway I will test your method now and let you know.

Comment: I did everything you said and I get `require(...) is not a function` in the console referring to the line `require('./routes/settings')(app);` in the `app.js`. Note that my version of posting in settings.js route is `exports.poster = function(app){
 return function(req,res){
  var dir = app.get('multimedia');
     console.log(dir); }
}`

Comment: Of course it throws an exception because you should pass the `app` parameter to `module.exports` function, but it is not present in `settings.js`. Change the `exports.poster` to `module.exports` if you want to use the approach 2.

Answer (score 0):

In settings.js

```
function settings(app) {
  console.log(app);
  // etc...
}

module.exports = settings;
```

In app.js:

```
var settings = require('./settings'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app), 
    ...
    ...

settings(app);
```

Basically you export the function from where you want to use them and then require those files in app.js.

*Sample project:*

server.js:

```
var settings= require('./settings'),
server = require('http');

settings(server);
```

settings.js:

```
function settings(server) {
  console.log("Hello");
  console.log(server);
}

module.exports = settings;
```

Both files are in the same folder.
To run: **node server**

Result:
[image]